# Why does this CAN message mean? It is the only one I get

Tags: lexus, can-bus

I am trying to reverse engineer my Lexus ES250 using an Arduino-based CAN sniffer. The connection seems to be OK as I am reading messages, but all I get are the two CAN messages bellow, looping forever..

```
45A,00,00,5A04004401000000
4E0,00,00,2400440100000000
```

I tried the same CAN Sniffer on a Toyota Yaris and it worked just fine.

1- What do these CAN messages mean?
2- How can I get to read the rest of the messages on the CAN bus?

Thanks a lot..

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: 1- It's completely vendor specific. Perhaps the central car access system broadcasting the status (key inserted or not, etc.).
2- What makes you think that there is more to get? Most of the interaction on CAN follows a request/response pattern. If you don't send "questions", you will not receive "answers.